# Yii2: why does the layout not get shown?

Tags: html, controller, yii2

I have a controller with a working action:

```
class ConfigurationController extends Controller {

    public function actions() {
        return [
            'error'   => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionView() {
        $myModel = ...
        $this->render('view', ['model' => $myModel]);
    }
}
```

All seems to be fine, however the layout file which is app/views/layout/main.php does not get shown. There is no special configuration about the layout. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason: I did not use the return statement. So the correct action is:

```
public function actionView() {
    $myModel = ...
    return $this->render('view', ['model' => $myModel]);
//  ^^^^^^
}
```

More info can be found in the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#action-results).

**Note:** Usually an empty page would be shown. But I also had a `<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>` without an `<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>` in the view file. This caused a partial rendering somehow (caused no exception). So I needed to correct this as well.

I'm just sharing my problem and what I've found out so if anyone else has a similar effect may be reminded that the return statement must not be forgotten.